# Как изменить значение одной координаты объекта геометрии окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget, move, геометрия

Как поменять одну координату “**`y`**” в `geometry`. 
Подскажите методы как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Window Geometry**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#window-geometry)

`QWidget` предоставляет несколько функций, которые имеют дело с геометрией виджета. 
Некоторые из этих функций работают с чистой клиентской областью
(т.е. с окном, исключая оконную рамку), 
другие включают оконную рамку.

- Включая рамку окна: `x()`, [**y()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#y-prop), `frameGeometry()`, `pos()` и [**move()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1).
- Исключая оконную рамку: `geometry()`, `width()`, `height()`, `rect()` и `size()`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(450, 200)                                              # !!!
        self.show()                                                        # !!!

        x = self.x()                                                       # !!!
        y = self.y() + 200                                                 # !!!
# ------------------>^^^^^

        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.move(x, y))                   # !!!
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self) 
        label = QLabel("Label 1")
        label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #B52B65;')
        layout.addWidget(label, 0)
        label1 = QLabel("Label 2")
        label1.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ED6663;')
        layout.addWidget(label1, 0 )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```